# mail validation with regex

Tags: regex, validation, email, email-validation

I want to make mail validation with regex but it's not working.where is my mistake? 
It's normally working but when I put a regex control its never see yes the mail you key in is enable for this regex format.

Here is my code;

**index.jsp**

```
 <head>
<title>Mail Control From Db</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="check.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div align="left">
<form name="chkForm" id="chkForm" method="post"  >
    <table>  
            <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20"  ></td>
                    <td>
                    <div id="emailInfo" align="left"></div>
                    </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**check.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {    
 var myForm = $("#chkForm"), email = $("#email"), emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");     


 //send ajax request to check email          
 email.blur(function()
 {          
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "email="+$(this).attr("value"),
    url: "check.jsp",

    beforeSend: function()
    {
        emailInfo.html("<font color='blue'>Kontrol Ediliyor..</font>");
    },//end beforeSend: function()



    success: function(data)
    {                   
        var reg = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;


        if (reg.test(email.val()))
        {
            var checkData = data.toString();
                if(checkData == 0)
                {  
                    emailok = false;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>Mail in use</font>");
                }//end if(checkData == 0)
                else if(checkData == 1)
                {
                    emailok = true;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='green'>Mail is not in use</font>");
                }//end else if(checkData == 1)

        }//end if (reg.test(email.val()))

        else
        {
            emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>ınvalid mail</font>");
        }//end else
  }// end success: function(data)


 });
 });//end email.blur(function()
 });//end $(document).ready(function()
```

I had a problem in check.jsp. and solved it.

1. problem is about regex.Regex was false.
2. condition was false. i change it with if (reg.test(email.val())).

Comment: Please, add your solution as *an Answer* and mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex only allows capital letters, so TEXT@EXAMPLE.COM would be okay but test@example.com not. You can change that either by adding the case-insensitive-flag to your regex

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i
```

or simply allow a-z in the regex itself

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/
```

But keep in mind that checking emails for validity is quite a difficult tasks to do, as the range of allowed mail-adresses is extremely broad and they even could contain special-chars like äüö etc. So your regex is not perfect, keep that in mind!

In PHP, I used [this function](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3) for years and it always seemed to work.

Why exactly are you using `.toString()` in this case? `.test()` gives you an boolean which you can perfectly check with `== false` - is there any reason why you want to convert this to a string?

Comment: is there any regex that you can advice to me then.
and its not still working i think i have a problem in there;
 if(reg.test(email).toString() == false)

Comment: i know thats a easy question but i am new in js.
how can we change that code ?
what do i have to write ?

Comment: Frankly I do not know if this function can be ported to javascript. Sorry.