# Generate Email address Regex

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying today to build a regex to make it match to email adress.

I've made one but not working in all the cases I want.

I would a Regex to match with all email address finishing with 2 characters after the dot or only the .com.

I hope to be clear enought,

- aaaaaa@bbbb.uk --> should work
- aaaaaa@bbbb.com --> should work
- aaaaaa@bbbb.cc --> should work
- aaaaaa@bbbb.ukk --> should not work
- aaaaaa@bbbb. --> should not work

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (void)
{
  int match;
  int err;
  regex_t preg;
  regmatch_t pmatch[5];
  size_t nmatch = 5;
  const char *str_request = "1aaaak@aaaa.ukk";

  const char *str_regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}";          

  err = regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_EXTENDED);
  if (err == 0)
    {
      match = regexec(&preg, str_request, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
      nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
      regfree(&preg);
      if (match == 0)
    {
          printf ("match\n");
          int start = pmatch[0].rm_so;
          int end  = pmatch[0].rm_eo;
          printf("%d - %d\n", start, end);
    }
      else if (match == REG_NOMATCH)
    {
          printf("unmatch\n");
    }
}
  puts ("\nPress any key\n");
  getchar ();
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17692873/4498831

Comment: If you search a little you will find *thousands* of variants of regular expressions to validate email addresses.

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.)+(uk|c(om|c))$`

Comment: @Morovaille stackoverflow.com/a/17692873/4498831 is bad, TLDs have not been nlimited to 6 characters for a long time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor for your answer but I don't want to only match with the .uk. It must match with .aa .uk .fr and all dot and 2 letters after it and also .com

Comment: There are hundreds of TLDs like .uk, .com. .net, .pictures - too many for a regex imo.

Comment: @AlexK. I posted a random answer about the subject, but as Joachim Pileborg wrote, there a thousands topics about it on the net, including SO. I'm pretty sure there is a suitable answer in SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot Moravaille for your so helpfull help!

Comment: I just need a regex to match to all the .aa and also the .com

Answer (score 0):

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.(com|[a-zA-Z]{2})$"
```

https://regex101.com/ is a very good tool for that

`\.` means a litteral dot ;

`(|)` means an alternative ;

`$` means the end of the line, as we do not want some trailing chars after the match.

Comment: is it working for you Moravaille ?

Comment: I tried it on the site, and it worked, yes.

Comment: I edited it : I forgot the end of line.

Comment: I've tried it on my code, replacing the .\ by .\\ to enable the gcc error main.cpp:25:27: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\.' [enabled by default]
 and it's matching every time, it's matching for aaaa@bbb.cccc and also aaaa@bbbb.ccc..

Comment: I edited it, retry, it works.

Comment: Thanks Moravaille, it's well working. Could you tell me what mean the $ at the end ?

Comment: You are welcome :) I edited for `$`. Please valid the answer if it works.

Comment: Does someone know why is not matching to   this line ?                        <font size=-1><a href="mailto:mrnours@citeweb.net">_ MR NOURS _</a></font>

Comment: I do not understand the question.